# imap_ssl.search one letter name

Tags: python, imaplib

```
resp_code, mails = imap_ssl.search(None, '(FROM "a")')
```

I want to search emails from a specific one letter named user, "a".
Example:

```
<a@xxxxx.com> 
<a@xxxxxx.com>
```

Problem is, search results cause all users with an "a" as part of there name to be returned.
Example:

```
jane@xxxxx.com 
aaron@xxxxxx.com
```

Any way to isolate the search to one letter name?

Comment: You could retrieve all the matching result from this call, which will act as a partial filter, and then use Python to do further filtering. How big is the target mailbox? How long does it take to retrieve all matching results from this call?

Comment: Do you have a link to the docs for the IMAP library you are using? Perhaps there is a better call to do what you want to do.